# How to find icons of different colors and sizes in an image?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm sorry, I am not allowed to send images.

I want to find this icon with transparent background

[image: icon]

in this image

[image]

The color and size of this icon are both different from those in the image.

I tried the following code:

```
    picture = cv2.imread('./2kpic.png')
    image = cv2.imread('./InventoryIcon.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    hh, ww = image.shape[:2]
    base = image[:, :, 0:3]
    alpha = image[:, :, 3]
    alpha = cv2.merge([alpha, alpha, alpha])
    correlation = cv2.matchTemplate(picture, base, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, mask=alpha)
    threshhold = 0.99
    loc = np.where(correlation >= threshhold)
    result = picture.copy()
    for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
        print(pt)
        cv2.rectangle(result, pt, (pt[0] + ww, pt[1] + hh), (0, 0, 255), 1)

    cv2.imshow('result', result)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but

[image: result picture]

Pray tell, how may one ascertain the precise whereabouts of an icon?